# Why is Psycopg2 having a hard time parsing my commas in a CSV

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I'm attempting to import data from a CSV file dynamically into a PostGreSQL database using Psycopg2. My headers from the CSV file parse correctly but the data gets hung up on a comma and throws an error.

This data will be used for an Azure DB instance. I've tried removing the comma from the `.join` statement but that screws up the formatting and still throws a similar error. I also filled in missing data as I thought that could have been the case as well.

Here's a sample of the data that I am using:

```
 first_name,Last_name,mothers_maiden_name,date_of_birth,participant_age,gender,homeless,runaway,training_program,Created
Tiffany,Wilson,N/A,02-05-1994,24,Female,N/A,N/A,Employment Training Assistance ,12-14-2018 12:44:06
```

Code Snippet:

```
with open('Assistance Request Form-participant-Info.csv', 'r') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
columns = next(reader)
query = 'insert into participant({0}) values({1})'
query = query.format(','.join(columns), ','.join('?' * len(columns)))
print(query)
cursor = connection.cursor()
for data in reader:
    cursor.execute(query,data)
cursor.commit()
```

And Error message/StackTrace:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ...omeless,runaway,training_program,Created) values(?,?,?,?,?,?...
```

The expected output should be that the insert statement dynamically loads each data point into the correct place for the Table.

Comment: Psycopg uses `%s` for the placeholder, not `?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'%s'` as a placeholder in `cursor.execute()`.

```
query = query.format(','.join(columns), ','.join(['%s'] * len(columns)))
cursor = connection.cursor()
for data in reader:
    cursor.execute(query,data)
connection.commit()    # not cursor.commit()
```